# mostrar Id en firebase en archivo handelbar

Tags: firebase, id

Quiero mostrar el id de la colección para mandar a hacer otra petición diferente, intente usando

```
<a href="/mosPer/{{adamp.key}}" class="sidebar-nav-link">
                  <span class="sidebar-nav-abbr">                    
                    <i data-feather="home"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="sidebar-nav-name">
                    Perfil
                  </span>
                </a>
```

pero no me muestra nada

Comment: Buen día, creo que falta mas contexto sobre tu error, ya que la parte de código que muestras no indica nada.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy trabajando con Nodejs y Firebase
Este es mi formulario (index.hbs)

```
<form action="/logNeg" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" class="form-label">Correo</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" name="algemaC" placeholder="email@example.com">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" name="algcontC" placeholder="Password">
              </div>              
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </form>
```

Este es mi archivo de rutas (index.js)

```
router.post('/logNeg',(req,res)=>{
    const {algemaC,algcontC} = req.body;
    db.ref('Negocio').orderByChild('negema').equalTo(algemaC).on('value', (snapshot)=>{
        const dtemp= snapshot.val();                        
        res.render('content/negemp',{adamp:dtemp})
    })        
})
```

Lo cual quiero mostrar en una etiqueta el id o bien en firebase @key (negemps.hbs) pero al revisar el código fuente no aparece la @key

```
<a href="/mosPer/{{adamp.key}}" class="sidebar-nav-link">
                  <span class="sidebar-nav-abbr">                    
                    <i data-feather="home"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="sidebar-nav-name">
                    Perfil
                  </span>
                </a>
```